# jruby : jdbc adapter requires :driver and :url (got :driver = )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am getting `jdbc adapter requires :driver and :url (got :driver = )`
 error whenever i hit any request to my jruby on rails application.

below is my database.yml file contain

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  jndi: jdbc/analyticscore

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  jndi: jdbc/analyticscore

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  jndi: jdbc/analyticscore

query:
  adapter: postgresql
  jndi: jdbc/harbinger
```

Please help me why i am getting error as "jdbc adapter requires :driver and :url (got :driver = )"

Comment: This application is not build by me. i am just trying to run it but getting this error. is there any java specific settings i have to implement.

Answer (score 0):

OK. finally I solved my own problem.

I downloaded postgresql driver from here https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html . please choose the appropriate driver as per your java version. put this driver in /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib directory and restart your glassfish server.

Thats it and you are done.